# get next or live element with jQuery find

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, find, jquery-selectors

Alright, not sure if `find()` will be the correct method for this. I am using [pretty photo](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) and I am loading some inline content. Basically when pretty photo launches, it clones what is defined inline and displays it in the lightbox.

The issue here is I cannot call `$("#myTextField").datepicker();` to activate a jQuery UI Datepicker on a text box. The reason being is it applies it to the invisible one I originally wrote, not the cloned one that is visible. I ran into this issue before with the `Submit` button in the inline content which I solved by using `$("#mySubmitButton").live('click',function().....`

I tried `$(this).find("#myTextField").next().datepicker();` but no dice. Any other suggestions? I dont know how else I could use the `live()` method.

Comment: I managed to get the datepicker pop up, except the datapicker isn't inserting the date when I click on a number. I am assuming its putting it in the original invisible content `$("#shoot_date").live("focus",function(){$(this).datepicker();});`

Comment: Check-out `.delegate()`, `.live()` has been depreciated as of jQuery 1.7: http://api.jquery.com/delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I figured it out via: [Jquery datepicker does not work inside lightbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392961/jquery-datepicker-does-not-work-inside-lightbox-solved)

```
$("#shoot_date").live("focus",function()
{
    $(this).attr("id","datepickerNEWID");                 
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because event for datepicker is not attached on any cloned element.

You can use prettyPhoto method changepicturecallback, to bind datepicker on cloned element. (based on [documentation](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/documentation/))

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
    changepicturecallback: function(){/* Called everytime an item is shown/changed */
        $("#myTextField").unbind("datepicker"); // this will unbind previous binded event
        $("#myTextField").datepicker(); // bind new event
    }
});
```

Or, try to add `$("#myTextField").datepicker();` inside inline element. Of course, in script tag. When prettyPhoto launchs, it will bind that event.

Comment: while the callback does get called in prettyphoto, the unbind and datepicker methods are still not created. I think they are still referencing the original content and not the cloned content

Comment: Do you use ID as selector or class? Try $('.pp_content_container .date_class').unbind("datepicker").datepicker();

Comment: ok that worked, however, none of the events on the calendar are working. When I try and select a date, I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'currentDay' of undefined`. I am thinking I need to go a different route for this to work

Comment: I get the same result if I just did: `$("#shoot_date").live("focus",function(){$(this).datepicker();});`. Same error that is

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an id selector like "#myTextField", consider using a class selector like ".dateField".

Having multiple elements on the same page with the same id is likely the source your trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the HTML structure of "Pretty Photo" (you can find this using FireBug or any other developer tools) then you can create a selector that finds the cloned element within the "Pretty Photo" element:

```
$('#pretty-photo-id').find('input[type="text"]').datepicker();
```

This is most likely not optimized for your situation but with the info I have this is about as specific as I can get.