# PrettyPhoto combined with DatePicker. Displayed properly but not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, prettyphoto

I'm using *Pretty Photo v3.1.3* and *jQuery UI v1.8.17*

I'm displaying inline content from my page with Pretty Photo:

```
<a rel = "pretty" onClick = "prepareProblemForm()" href = "#form" title = "" >Form</span></a>
//...
<div id = "form-details" style = "display: none;"></div>
//...
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a[rel^='pretty']").prettyPhoto();
    });
</script>
```

The section of code inserted by `prepareProblemForm()` which will be displayed with PrettyPhoto is:

```
<script>
    $(function() { 
        $('#date').live('click', function () {
            $(this).datepicker('destroy').datepicker({showOn: 'both'}).focus();
        });
});
</script>
<form>
    //...
</form>
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392961/jquery-datepicker-does-not-work-inside-lightbox-solved) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386718/jquery-live-failing-with-jquery-ui-datepicker). I made the date picker to be displayed properly but when I try to press a date which should be displayed in the text field nothing happens. Sometime instead of the text a new button (which if pressed it opens the date picker) inside the DOOM