# jQuery triggered newly added html code

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Example I had 2 html input

```
<div class="wrap">        
   <input class="autocomplete" name="auto_1" />
   <input class="autocomplete" name="auto_2" />
</div>
```

The `auto_1` and `auto_2` is using auto complete by jQuery UI and triggered when document ready `$(function(){})`

And then if we click a button on my website, there will be another one button. Added by function `$('.wrap').append('<input class="autocomplete" name="auto_3" />')`

And now total there will be 3 input

```
<div class="wrap">        
   <input class="autocomplete" name="auto_1" />
   <input class="autocomplete" name="auto_2" />
   <input class="autocomplete" name="auto_3" />
</div>
```

But the autocomplete function is not running on `auto_3` because it's newly added.

How to make it running/use autocomplete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is not with click on new input but with autocomplete on new input. When you add new element with

```
$('.wrap').append('<input class="autocomplete" name="auto_3" />')
```

You must attach autocomplete to this new field, so

```
$('input[name="auto_3"]').autocomplete();
```

Or make autocomplete with livequery plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4551313/657584

Answer (score 1):

Use `.on()` : http://api.jquery.com/on

```
$('.wrap').on('click', '.autocomplete', function(){
    // your code here
    // $(this).autocomplete(); // or whatever.
});
```

Using the `.on()` method you delegate your click handler to existant and future elements that will be added to the DOM, something like the (newly) deprecated (from jQ 1.7) `.live()`

From the DOCS:

```
$("a.offsite").live("click", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); });   // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate("a.offsite", "click", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); });  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on("click", "a.offsite", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); }); // jQuery 1.7+
```

Comment: Like RPM said. You surely use an **outdated jQ v.**

Comment: i using the lastest update, the function `.on()` is working for the `auto_1` and `auto_2` but not on `auto_3`

Comment: @RPM no, `on.` allows you to delegate your element, so it's a better substitution.