# Adding a usable button to .AppendTo - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

Basically I've created a overlay and load this into appendTo as a 'loading screen'.

Recently, I needed to add a Stop button to the overlay which isn't a problem, however the jquery .click function isn't picking up the button click, I've tried keeping the existing button and therefore it would maybe register, but sadly hasn't.

(I've also tried using an Id for the button too.

Below is some test code to demonstrate the problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addButton").click( function () {
        $overlay = $("<div id='overlay'><div id='contain'><h3 style='color:#FFF'>Processing, just a moment</h3> <div id='stop'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' id='stop1' >Stop</button></div><div class='bar' style='width: 80%; padding-top:50%'></div></div></div");
        $overlay.appendTo(document.body);
        $("#stop").click( function() {
            alert("working");
        });
    });
```

Edit:

Just to clarify, this is what I originally wanted, however due to 'over changes' the above example will work in my scenario, this is the original problem just for clarity.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#addButton").click( function () {
            $overlay = $("<div id='overlay'><div id='contain'><h3 style='color:#FFF'>Processing, just a moment</h3> <div id='stop'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' id='stop1' >Stop</button></div><div class='bar' style='width: 80%; padding-top:50%'></div></div></div");
            $overlay.appendTo(document.body);

        });

$("#stop").click( function() {
                alert("working");
            });

});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery triggered newly added html code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677194/jquery-triggered-newly-added-html-code)

Comment: worksforme: http://jsfiddle.net/3HMcT/

Comment: @samjudson: No, this is different. `#stop` will be in the DOM before `$('#stop').click(...)` is called to bind a handler to it.

Comment: Sorry, yes. Try using $("#stop1") instead, as you are adding the click to the div, not the button.

Comment: Sorry people I miss wrote the example above, but upon reflection having the update function within my addButton may be a viable solution.

Comment: Yeah this will work, thanks all :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that too. See the [docs for the `on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addButton").click( function () {
        $overlay = $("<div id='overlay'><div id='contain'><h3 style='color:#FFF'>Processing, just a moment</h3> <div id='stop'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' id='stop1' >Stop</button></div><div class='bar' style='width: 80%; padding-top:50%'></div></div></div");
        $overlay.appendTo(document.body);
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#stop", function() {
        alert("working");
    });
});
```

This adds only one click listener to the document, which fires every time a click event bubbles from a `#stop` element. However, this is usually only needed for many elements, so you should better use a class "`stop`" when there's more than one such button.

Yet, I guess you will need the closure which you had in your first example to execute the right onclick-actions.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addButton").on('click', function() {
        $overlay = $("<div id='overlay'><div id='contain'><h3 style='color:#FFF'>Processing, just a moment</h3> <div id='stop'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' id='stop1' >Stop</button></div><div class='bar' style='width: 80%; padding-top:50%'></div></div></div");
        $overlay.appendTo(document.body);
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#stop', function() {
        alert("working");
    });
});
```

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, I noticed! And no, I did not copy your code, just wrote almost the same thing?

Comment: I know you could not have copied it, but I really thought it would be exactly the same :-) Just starting to realize the little differences... +1 for the double use of .on()

Answer (score 0):

Use `.live()` so that anything newly created will still get the `click` event.
http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/2GCfD/

[image]

> It is working now.

Comment: Live is deprecated in favor of "on"