# jQuery .on? Manipulating DOM after Ajax

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bind jQuery UI autocomplete using .live()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551230/bind-jquery-ui-autocomplete-using-live)

I can't seem to figure this out.  I believe that I will have to either use .load() or .on() but I can't figure out how to make either of them work.

So I have a Table with 3 Rows.  When the users fills out the 3 rows I want to provide them with more.

Once they fill out the last row this script is called.

```
function addNewRow(id)
{
    var qty = $('#qty' + id).val();
    if (qty > 0)
    {
        $('#quickaddtable').append('<?php echo createRow(($i+1)); ?>');
    }
}
```

The problem is that I am using autocomplete and for the newly created rows it's not working.  I know that I need to reload DOM but I am just lost at how I can easily do this.

```
$(function(){  

    $(".id").autocomplete({ 
            //My Code
    });  
});
```

I am sure this is a simple answer however almost all the examples showed .on("click",...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bind jQuery UI autocomplete using .live()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551230/bind-jquery-ui-autocomplete-using-live) <-- [also applies to `.on()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551230/bind-jquery-ui-autocomplete-using-live#comment13620250_4551230)

Comment: What does `.id` refer to - is that a field inside each row?

Comment: id is just an autoincrementing number to identify each row  <input id="qty1">...

Comment: Neal got it. I was looking at it all wrong.

I needed to use .on with the autocomplete not the addNewRow function.

So I changed this

    $j(function(){  
      
     //attach autocomplete  
     $j(document).on("keyup.autocomplete", '.autocomplete', function(){
      $j(this).autocomplete({
                       //My Code
             });
     });

Comment: How can I credit Neal with answering this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neal got it. I was looking at it all wrong.

I needed to use .on with the autocomplete not the addNewRow function.

So I changed this

```
$j(function(){  

    //attach autocomplete  
    $j(document).on("keyup.autocomplete", '.autocomplete', function(){
        $j(this).autocomplete({
                   //My Code
            });
    });

})
```

Thank you for all help.  I spent hours looking at this and in Minutes you guys responded thank you again.  Since Neil didn't post a answer is there any way I can give him credit?

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that when the  `$('.id')` selector is used, the new rows don't exist yet. When you add more rows, the new elements that match '.id' aren't bound to the method you called earlier.

I would probably just rebind the after you insert rather than play around with binding to the document (`$(document).on('event')`). So it would be something like:

```
$('#quickaddtable').append( ... );
$('.id').autocomplete("destroy");
$('.id').autocomplete({ ... });
```

Comment: I am not looking to do a post. the jQuery monitors the number off rows and adds them accordingly.  No post or ajax is required.  I guess I could create and call a new page however .append works great at adding the rows.  Just prevents the autocomplete from working

Comment: I see - so you have a PHP page, on your server, that contains this js. I made an assumption that this was a stand-alone script, in which you were trying to execute PHP from the client. I understand now. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Neal actually pegged it in his Comment.  I was looking at it wrong.  I was trying to do a on with the addRow function when I need to do it with the auto complete.  now I just need to write his answer with on instead of live which is depreciated