# jQuery datepicker loses focus after .("show")

Tags: jquery-ui, focus, datepicker

I'm using the range date-picker of jQuery UI. When selecting the "from date", I want to open automatically the "to date" date-picker. So, I call the .datepicker("show"). The "to date" picker is showing for a second and immediately fade away. Surprisingly, if I go to another application and then come back and focus on the browser window, the "to date" picker is shown.
I also tried to add the $('#toDate').focus(); but it didn't help.

```
$( ".fromDatePicker" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    altFormat: 'yymmdd',
    altField: "#fromDateFormatted",
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "images/calender_icon_a1.jpg", 
    buttonText: "open calendar",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        $('#toDate').datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        $('#toDate').datepicker("show");
        //$('#toDate').focus();  //commented cause it's not working
    }
});
```

Comment: See if this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386718/jquery-live-failing-with-jquery-ui-datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the flashing appearance is because `show` would be called before `minDate` finishes. This would confuse datepicker when triggering `beforeShowDay` event just before showing the picker.

One somewhat hacky workaround is to delay the call to show the datepicker. For example, something like the following would work:

```
onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
    $('#toDate').datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
    setTimeout(function() { $('#toDate').datepicker("show") }, 50);
}
```

See this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/PVuTC/2/.